# React-dnd drag update db in mongo with meteor inorder to persist order when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor, react-dnd

I am using react-dnd drag and drop and have a sorted list that gets mapped through, it works somewhat I am able to drag and drop and on refresh it seems things stayed in the right position but the element moves one row than where I dragged it.

The main issue is when I drag the item and drop it the cards state in the `moveCardDb` is different slightly then outside the function, why it would be different at that point I can't seem to figure out.

Here is a minimal setup of what I have
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-goodall-qu43p?file=/src/Container.jsx

If you look at the console log on the moveCardDb function you will see the cards stae variable slightly out of order

Thanks ahead of time

I have the following code for the drag and drop

The mapping function and update of position

```
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  let stateReplace = useMemo(() => {
    if (!isLoading && formBuilder?.inputs?.length) {
      return formBuilder.inputs;
    }
    return [];
  }, [isLoading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(stateReplace);
  }, [setCards, stateReplace]);

  // console.log(cards);

  const moveCard = useCallback(
    (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
      console.log(dragIndex);
      console.log(hoverIndex);
      const dragCard = cards[dragIndex];
      setCards(
        update(cards, {
          $splice: [
            [dragIndex, 1],
            [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
          ],
        })
      );
    },
    [cards]
  );

  const moveCardDb = useCallback(() => {
    //console.log(cards);

    Meteor.call("formLeadBuilderDrag.update", cards, params._id, function (
      error,
      result
    ) {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, [cards]);

  const renderCard = (card, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        {isLoading ? (
          <div className="loading">loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Card
              key={card.dragPositionId}
              index={index}
              id={card.dragPositionId}
              input={card.inputType}
              moveCard={moveCard}
              moveCardDb={moveCardDb}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div className="loading">loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <form>
          <div style={style}>{cards.map((card, i) => renderCard(card, i))}</div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

The card rendered

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useDrag, useDrop } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "./ItemTypes";
const style = {
  border: "1px dashed gray",
  padding: "0.5rem 1rem",
  marginBottom: ".5rem",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  cursor: "move",
};
export const Card = ({ id, input, index, moveCard, moveCardDb }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.CARD,
    hover(item, monitor) {
      if (!ref.current) {
        return;
      }
      const dragIndex = item.index;
      const hoverIndex = index;
      // Don't replace items with themselves
      if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) {
        return;
      }
      // Determine rectangle on screen
      const hoverBoundingRect = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
      // Get vertical middle
      const hoverMiddleY =
        (hoverBoundingRect.bottom - hoverBoundingRect.top) / 2;
      // Determine mouse position
      const clientOffset = monitor.getClientOffset();
      // Get pixels to the top
      const hoverClientY = clientOffset.y - hoverBoundingRect.top;
      // Only perform the move when the mouse has crossed half of the items height
      // When dragging downwards, only move when the cursor is below 50%
      // When dragging upwards, only move when the cursor is above 50%
      // Dragging downwards
      if (dragIndex < hoverIndex && hoverClientY < hoverMiddleY) {
        return;
      }
      // Dragging upwards
      if (dragIndex > hoverIndex && hoverClientY > hoverMiddleY) {
        return;
      }
      // Time to actually perform the action
      moveCard(dragIndex, hoverIndex);
      moveCardDb();
      // Note: we're mutating the monitor item here!
      // Generally it's better to avoid mutations,
      // but it's good here for the sake of performance
      // to avoid expensive index searches.
      item.index = hoverIndex;
    },
  });
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: ItemTypes.CARD, id, index },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
  const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;
  drag(drop(ref));
  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ ...style, opacity }}>
      <p>{input}</p>
      <input
        name={input + id}
        defaultValue="test"
        // ref={register}
      />
      {/* <button type="button" onClick={onEditToggle}>
        <BiEditAlt size={25} />
      </button> */}
      {/* <button onClick={() => deleteLead(leads)}>&times;</button> */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My Object from the beginning

```
{
  "_id": "showRoomId",
  "type": "Show Room Lead",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-14",
  "userId": "83nfd298dn382",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "inputType": "shortText",
      "dragPositionId": "1",
      "label": "First Name:"
    },
    {
      "inputType": "phoneNumber",
      "dragPositionId": "2",
      "label": "Cell Phone Number"
    },
    {
      "inputType": "email",
      "dragPositionId": "3",
      "label": "Work Email"
    },
    {
      "inputType": "Address",
      "dragPositionId": "4",
      "label": "Home Address"
    },
    {
      "inputType": "multipleChoice",
      "dragPositionId": "5",
      "label": "Preferred Method of Contact",
      "options": [
        {
          "dragPositionId": "1",
          "label": "Email"
        },
        {
          "dragPosition": "2",
          "label": "Cell Phone"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inputType": "dropDown",
      "dragPositionId": "6",
      "label": "How did you find us?",
      "options": [
        {
          "dragPositionId": "1",
          "label": "Google"
        },
        {
          "dragPosition": "2",
          "label": "Referral"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting a time on a function on the monitor.didDrop function. It seems a bit hacky to me, so if anyone can offer a better solution let me know. I also decided to store to localstorage first, and then wil submit to database on form submit.

```
 const [{ isDragging, didDrop }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: ItemTypes.CARD, id, index },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      didDrop: monitor.didDrop(),
    }),
  });
  const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;

  function droppy(dropped) {
    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

    setTimeout(function () {
      dropped();
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
  }

  if (didDrop) {
    droppy(moveCardDb);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided a bunch of code, which is good, but I am not clear on where the problem is, and the things you have tried to attempt to remedy it. Are things stored in the DB as you expect, or is it a rendering problem?

Comment: Things are stored in the DB, as a new array sorted in the order that was outputted buy the cards state variable. However it is slightly off in order, because the correct state renders after the moveCardDb is fired, so it's sees it's previous position by 1 and keeps it there on refresh. I think I can get a working example without the db, but it if it will console the incorrect order inside the moveCardDb function. I will do that now

Comment: Sorry, that should have been a comment, not an answer. So what you are seeing is some kind of race condition, ie the save is firing at the wrong time, before the order has been set correctly?

Comment: I think so yes, I put up a code sandbox and if you view the console you can see where it's out of order by one and thats the point I save it do my db